# How can i use cognito user pool as a authencation and authorization server for my private docker registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cognito

I have run my private docker container with httpasswd authentication.Now i want to use aws congnito as my authentication and authorization server.I know cognito oauth2 supported and so docker private registry.
so how can i configure congnito and docker registry? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a good question for SO. Please narrow down the scope. Write what you have already tried and what exactly does not work. As it is now, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: Thanks for reply. we cognito is a ouath2 suported platform. It is also known that  docker private registry is also oauth2 supported from here https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/. So how can i configure cognito userpool and docker registry sothat cognito provide jwt tocken to autorize docker registry.
i hope its clear now. If you need any more anymore information, let me know please.

Comment: Cognito is OIDC IdP, not OAuth2. The token returned by it is not compatible with OAuth2. Anyhow, please be more specific. What have you already tried? Show some code. What are the errors you are getting? Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask